# tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot write: Input/output error when taking backup

Tags: linux, tar, scsi, tape

When I try to take backup of data more than 1MB in a tape (LTO3) using tar command it showing me the following error.

```
xyz@localhost# tar -cvf /dev/nst0 file1.tar
file1.tar
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot write: Input/output error
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Output of `mt -f /dev/st0 status`:

```
SCSI 2 tape drive:
File number=0, block number=0, partition=0.
Tape block size 0 bytes. Density code 0x44 (LTO-3).
Soft error count since last status=0
General status bits on (41010000):
BOT ONLINE IM_REP_EN
```

Output of `dmesg`:

```
st0: Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
st0: Add. Sense: Information unit iuCRC error detected
```

and

```
st0: <<vendor>> ASC=0xff ASCQ=0xffASC=0xff <<vendor>> ASCQ=0xff
Errata on LSI53C1030 occurredsc->req_bufflen=0x2800, xfer_cnt=0x00,difftransfer= 0x1400
st0: Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
Info fld=0x1400
```

Output of `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`:

```
Attached devices:
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
Vendor: NECVMWar Model: VMware IDE CDR10 Rev: 1.00
Type: CD-ROM ANSI SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
Vendor: VMware Model: Virtual disk Rev: 1.0
Type: Direct-Access ANSI SCSI revision: 02
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
Vendor: HP Model: Ultrium 3-SCSI Rev: G54W
Type: Sequential-Access ANSI SCSI revision: 03
Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 02 Lun: 00
Vendor: HP Model: 1x8 autoloader Rev: 1.50
Type: Medium Changer ANSI SCSI revision: 03
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this line in the log:

```
st0: Sense Key : Medium Error [current]
```

it looks like either the tape is damaged or dirty, or the drive head is dirty or misaligned or damaged. First thing to try is to run a cleaning tape through the drive, then try writing to that tape again. If you get media errors again, try writing to a known good tape, or to a brand new tape. Do not put tapes with valuable data into the drive until you've found a solution - the drive might damage any tape put into it.

This drive appears to be part of a library. The library may provide additional information it has retrieved from the drive about the error (in particular, whether it thinks it was a drive error or a tape error). The info should be visible on the front panel and/or over the network.

Comment: thanks For your reply.

after clean the tape still i am facing the same issue..!!!!

Comment: now i am using new tape but again facing the same issue. Till 128KB its working fine but after that its showing input output error.

Comment: I'd like to see exactly how much gets written before the error occurs. `tar` doesn't give that kind of info. Instead of `tar cvf /dev/nst0 file`, can you instead run `tar cvf - file | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=64k`. See whether it fails on the first 64KB record or whether it writes one or more successfully. Also, does your library's front panel show any errors on the drive?

Comment: does your library's front panel show any errors on the drive?
NO,

but i can write file of size 15k in tape and also able to retirieve.

Comment: output of the following command

tar cvf - xyz.tar.gz | dd of=/dev/nst0 bs=64k

xyz.tar.gz
dd: writing `/dev/nst0': Input/output error
3+0 records in
2+0 records out
131072 bytes (131 kB) copied, 2.87548 s, 45.6 kB/s

Comment: Do you get the same result (2 64KB records out before getting an error) when you use another tape?

Comment: yes,i am getting the same error even after changing the tape.

Comment: according to the HP LTO document To enable large transfers to tape under Linux (>64 KB per write),

i have to set the ST_BUFFER_BLOCKS for that i have to edit the file /usr/src/linux/drivers/scsi/st_options.h and change the definition of ST_BUFFER_BLOCKS

but the file st_options.h is not present in my centos6.5 is there any other way through which i can set buffer block or it is having different name...???

Comment: I don't have any more ideas about what could be causing your problems aside from there being problem in the tape drive hardware, especially if it was working fine before and just started to fail a month ago. If the library has a menu item to run diagnostics, try that.

Comment: You should probably ask your kernel question as a separate question. To get you started, read http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source to see how to download the kernel source. The kernel-devel package doesn't have the st driver, so you'll need to download the full kernel source. Centos 6.5 comes with kernel 2.6; the HP document, if it's written with LTO3 in mind, may be almost 10 years old and may refer to older versions of the kernel, with different variable and macro names, so keep that in mind.